# Trouble accessing Docker interactive mode image

Tags: ssh, docker, interactive

I need help with accessing interactive mode of Docker image thanks to lack of knowledge in needed area.

I want open file , and read from file, and use image filesystem (traversal and search).

I think I need interactive mode for that because I haven't succeeded to do that using exec command.  (reading from txt file in docker image)

I've been trying to do this for few days and now I have only 1 day left so I desperately ask for help here. I tried to do this both on Docker on Ubuntu and on Windows.

Commands and error messages I tried

```
sudo docker run -d x/x:x 
docker run -d x/x:x
docker run -it x
docker run -dit x/x:x
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash x
docker run -it  x/x:x bash
docker run -itd x/x:x sh
docker run -it x sh
```

Pictures better explain those failed attempts (commands and errors).

Errors with Ubuntu Docker:
[errors Ubuntu Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQekN.png)

Errors with Windows Docker:
[Errors Windows Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA8BJ.png)

Comment: Also see this if you created your images from scratch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535015/error-cannot-start-container-stat-bin-sh-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the last error of your pictures, it means that the image used does not has `bash` installed.

As an alternative, you can open an interactive terminal using `sh` instead. I tried this with success:

`docker run -it cuspajzodgraha/diverto-ctf:spyware /bin/sh`

Comment: Thank you, this solved problem.